# Mp4 download using python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

So I've been working on a webscraping script to download a video from a specific website I'm done **scraping** the site and have the video source.
The video has a play botton I've tried using selenium on it it plays but I don't know how to perform the download using selenium. Also I tried this other codes

```
wget.download('http://wwwstatic.chia-anime.tv/player.php?id=96576')
```

I also tried using the request library iter tools
But that only downloads 14.4kb

Also I observed the direct link (above link) that plays the video has a click botton and when it's clicked it sends a network request to another site but I don't know how to replicate it

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You want to wget the actual file, not the php page.

I got the video link from the page so this should work.

`wget.download('https://animesource.me:7995/cache/TDJgNsh-ZXf5Qd81-24vVg/1584877220/j1vznzzjn5ns.html.mp4')`

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to scrape to get that link then use wget to download it. But I can't seem to get this particular link from that video using my script,                                            A = requests.get('http://wwwstatic.chia-anime.tv/player.php?id=96576

B = Beautifulsoup(A.text, "html.parser")

Now from this I want to collect that link you just gave me 

How do I go about that ?

Comment: @DerrickVincent Visit the page and parse it. It is in a div class called jw-media jw-reset

Comment: that's what I'm saying the link for download can't be found even after parsing. After parsing it I checked the entire page source but it's not there, what happens it when the play botton is clicked the site sends a network request to another server to retrieve that video. My problem is replicating how the network sends the request to the server.

Comment: @DerrickVincent You can use selenium to replicate the click

Comment: I've actually done that but still can't get the main download link. Driver find element by xpath then click, then I also did driver.page_source still nothing. Could u attempt writing the code and see if you can get the link